# ASPxGridView GetRowValues gets old value

Tags: sql, asp.net, aspxgridview

I do have an ASPxGridView and there is data on it i have changed one of the columns dataitem template and added an ASPxSpinEdit but when i try to add values from gridview to sql it inserts old value not value from the ASPxSpinEdit.

could you please say me what should i do to get value from ASPxSpinEdit .
here is my insert code;

```
  using (VeriIslem veri=new Veri.VeriIslem())
            {


                veri.InsertUpdateDelete(string.Format(@"
INSERT INTO _PLT_B2B_SEPET
(CARI_KOD, STOK_KODU, FIYAT, ISK1, ISK2, ISK3, GENEL_ISKONTO, NET_FIYAT, PLASIYER_KODU, SIPARIS_NO, KAYIT_TARIHI,MIKTAR)
SELECT 
'10017','{0}',REPLACE('{1}',',','.'),0,0,0,0,REPLACE('{1}',',','.'),'1',NULL,GETDATE() ,REPLACE('{2}',',','.')
",
 ASPxGridView1.GetRowValues(e.VisibleIndex,"STOK_KODU").ToString(),
 ASPxGridView1.GetRowValues(e.VisibleIndex, "FIYAT").ToString(),
  ASPxGridView1. GetRowValues(e.VisibleIndex,"MIKTAR").ToString()
 ));
```

Comment: You are only inserting the values, not Updating it. That is why it is taking the OLD Values. You need to write `onRowUpdate` command of the gridview

Comment: thanks,could you please say me how can i update the certain row or when can i find document for it,

Comment: @NadeemKhan that code sample is updating database , but i am reading values from one table and i want to insert values to another table like there is a standart price list and i want to make discount for one and save that values to my table